# How StarDock's ModernMix work?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I found StarDock's ModernMix today, with it we can run Windows 8 modern applications on classic desktop.

Do we know how it works?

Thanks,
Navneet

Comment: I'd really like to know how it works. There is an option in visual studio to debug Metro apps on the desktop that uses a kind of VNC client. I'm guessing MetroMix either does that, or it hooks into the drawing API (for lack of a better term) beneath Metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some control (ActiveX?) that can run a Metro App, but that's probably not publicly documented anywhere