# What desktop does Metro stuff run in?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, microsoft-metro, win32gui

Just curious, from a standpoint of WinAPI developer, what [desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do Metro apps run in?

This stuff:

[image]

Comment: This is an implementation detail and is subject to change. What is your practical programming question?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Knowledge. Other than that, I may need to display a popup notification if a Metro app is running.

Comment: There is a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586098/how-stardocks-modernmix-work) already, but apparently nobody knows. Still, even more than the technical underpinning, I would like to know how such a demented decision, to run the apps in fullscreen mode, could first be made and then implemented and rolled out and then ... customer feedback ignored. It's so unbelievable, so fantastic, I would really like to know the how-it-could-at-all-be-possible of it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: RaymondChen probably does, but he wouldn't say, would he?

Comment: This is quickly going off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: It's a trick question, because nobody uses Metro :)

Answer (score 26):

I didn't know that it would be such a secret... so I had to do some investigating and here's what I found:

First off, to answer my original question -- the Metro (or Modern UI) stuff runs in the exact same [desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the "desktop" apps (pardon the pun.) It is actually all very simple. The short answer -- all *Microsoft approved* Metro stuff runs in the `Internet Explorer_Server` container (which, in layman's terms, is the Internet Explorer); or in the [`DirectUIHWND`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd) container (which is Microsoft's proprietary class that renders their undocumented UI), all in windows with the [`WS_EX_TOPMOST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style turned on, which makes them render on top of the other content. And that is it!

Here's a couple of examples:

Let's split the desktop and use `Spy++` to see what's happening under the hood:

[image]

So if we look into the "Weather" app window, it is nothing more than the *regular* (Win32) window of the class "`Internet Explorer_Server`" that is housed in the window of the "`Web Platform Embedding`" class, which in turn sits in the "`Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`" container that has the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` and `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` styles on:

[image]

If you look even deeper, all Microsoft's Metro *stuff* seems to run from the [`WWAHOST.exe`](http://www.groovypost.com/tips/wwahost-exe-windows-process-safe-running-or-virus/) process, which in simple terms is the container to run JavaScript for the Metro apps.

Now let's look into the [Start Screen](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/start-screen-tutorial) itself. Since it completely covers the desktop we need to use a different tool and its Shift key snapshot capability to get to it:

[image]

From it we can get the Start Screen's window handle (or `0x10158` in my case) and look it up in the Spy++:

[image]

As you can see from both tools, the Start Screen has window class [`DirectUIHWND`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089196/netuihwnd-and-directuihwnd), that is housed inside a window of the `ImmersiveLauncher` class, that is the one with the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` and `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` styles that make it remain on top. And that is the only difference between *it* and any other window created by a "desktop" app.

What is also interesting is how the "desktop" itself is rendered in case of a split-window situation. I originally assumed that in this case the desktop is simply shifted (or moved) to one side and resized, but that *is not* what happens... In reality (or in my Windows 8.1) in case of a split between a desktop and a Metro app, the metro app simply covers over the desktop, but the desktop itself *does not* change its position or size. In that case, only the taskbar and the existing desktop windows are moved and resized to fit the split. This could be illustrated by this diagram:

[image]

As a side note, such moving and resizing can be quite annoying for a user, since original positions and sizes of the desktop windows are not restored when the split goes away.

And lastly, a somewhat unexpected finding. I decided to check how Google folks were able to implement their Chrome browser (running as a Metro app) and found this:

[image]

Chrome renders in the `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow` class window, belonging to the Google's own process: "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`". So without going any deeper, it is evidently possible to encapsulate a Metro-style app in a non-Microsoft container, which is a good news for developers that don't care about AppStore XAML apps :)

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, if you plan to show your own popup message from a Win32 process that is visible on top of a Metro app, you need to do the following:

- Set `UIAccess="true"` in the process manifest. You can do so in the Visual Studio by going to `Project Properties` -> `Linker` -> `Manifest Files` and set `UAC Bypass UI Protection` to YES. (Note that you can keep `UAC Execution Level` as `asInvoker`, or not to require elevation of your process.)
- Code-sign your process. It is important, since without a signature it won't work, and you'll see this error message: "*A referral was returned from the server.*"

[image]

An alternative to signing (or for testing purposes on your development system) you can set the following [registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232764.aspx) to 0. (I haven't tried it though, and I **wouldn't recommend it** due to obvious security concerns! But it seems to be another way to test it if a code-signing certificate is not available.)

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ValidateAdminCodeSignatures
```

- Place the compiled executable file either into the `%windir%\System32` folder, or more realistically into the `%ProgramFiles%\Company\Product`, or into the alternative `%ProgramFiles(X86)%\Company\Product` folder for your product's installation location.

Also you may consider reading [Raymond Chen's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/13/10377004.aspx) about this topic.

- After that, when you set the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style on your popup window, it will be displayed above any other windows, including the Metro apps, Start Screen, etc.

So in other words, doing this:

```
//You may also consider setting the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style
::SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0 , 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Can achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since you say that your actual issue is knowing whether a Metro app is running, the answer is to call `IAppVisibility::GetAppVisibilityOnMonitor`. Pass the monitor you want to check. Note that this will give the correct answer regardless of what desktop the applications run in.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. Although I'm not totally clear how I'd call it from a Win32 app?

Comment: As it says in the docs, [call the `CoCreateInstance` function with `CLSID_AppVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj554119(v=vs.85).aspx). This gives you an object that supports `IAppVisiblity`. Call the `GetAppVisibilityOnMonitor` method.

Comment: Thank you, Raymond. I tried to implement this interface in VS 2008 but it doesn't have the definitions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23207291/843732 Any idea how to do that prior to VS 2012?

Comment: The interface was introduced in Windows 8, so you will need to install the Platform SDK for Windows 8.