# How to use IAppVisibility from a VS project prior to VS 2012?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, windows-8

I'm trying to use the [IAppVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj554119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface (and namely the [IAppVisibility::GetAppVisibilityOnMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj554124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method) from my C++ project that is developed under Visual Studio 2008. I found [this code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Start-screen-visibility-b1a72059), that unfortunately requires VS 2012 to compile.

So I was curious, is there a way to call it from a VS project prior to VS 2012?

For instance, I'm doing this:

```
#include <Shobjidl.h>   //Earlier version

IAppVisibility* pAppVis = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AppVisibility, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                      IID_IAppVisibility, (void**) &pAppVis);
```

That results in the following errors:

```
error C2065: 'IAppVisibility' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'IID_IAppVisibility' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Sounds like you are just missing a `#include` to the file containing the missing definitions. Or a `#import` of the dll containing the component implementation (which will generate the corresponding `.tlh` file)

Comment: @user1793036: Yeah, I get that. But what include do I need?

Comment: Naturally, VS 2012 will not come with interfaces defined in 2013. You need to upgrade your header files by installing the corresponding Platform SDK.